# How to return SqlDataReader in C# WCF?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf

In my C# WCF service I have a `SqlDataReader` that holds rows of data that I would like to return to the client.

How to return everything in the `SqlDataReader`?

Right now I have

```
if (sqlReader != null)
{
    if (sqlReader.HasRows)
    {
        while (sqlReader.Read())
        {
            return sqlReader[0].ToString();
        }
        sqlConn.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

That only returns the first result. The return type of the class is string at the moment.
I was thinking of something like array in array, but I am not sure how?

EDIT:

Thanks for the many replies. I am interested in returning the entire SQL data that the service 'creates'. Not online the first column ([0]) - this was only for testing.

But I am not sure on how to get everything from the service back to the client.

- How to return it?

For eg. in Powershell I would create a collection and add objects to that collection, if I had to pass it between clients.

I am looking for something similar in C# and WCF.

Many thanks so far :)

EDIT #2:

Got it! :)

Created a new class (e.g.):

```
public class ObjectNotification
{
    public string AlertDescription;
    public string Servername; 
}
```

In my svc.cs file in top:

```
List<ObjectNotification> objlist = new List<ObjectNotification>();
```

And

```
    if (sqlReader.HasRows)
    {
       while (sqlReader.Read())
       {
             ObjectNotification obj = new ObjectNotification();
             obj.AlertDescription = sqlReader["AlertDescription"].ToString();
             obj.Servername = sqlReader["ComputerName"].ToString();
             objlist.Add(obj);
       }
    }
    return objlist;
```

That gave me exactly what I wanted :)

Best regards

Comment: Classes don't have a return type.  Did you mean the method?  Can you post the entire method where you're using the `SqlDataReader`?

Comment: I think it would be a lot of extra work and requiring a lot of changes of the design of your code (so I won't post this as an answer) but the real answer is you have to use [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/odata.aspx), however the way you use it is very different than normal WCF.

Comment: there is also a flaw in the code, the first time you hit the return statement the control exists the loop forever, returning in fact only the first row....

Comment: @user1281991 A few hints from my point of view: You could use a struct instead of a class if you only need 2 attributes to bundle. A class makes sense if you wanna add methods. The name 'ObjectNotification' sounds not so good for a class imo. A class name should be clear at first sight if somebody else wanna read your code. It is really good that you created your solution. :-)

Comment: I still prefer: DataTable dt=new DataTable();     
dt.Load(datareader); List<ObjectNotification> objList=(List<ObjectNotification>) dt.ToList<ObjectNotification>(); once you get the dt.tolist going you have a code that you can reuse again and again.... and it's really great if you have an object with 50 properties ;)

Comment: @mnemonic thank you very much for that hint. I have created a struct instead and still works perfectly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// for instance
List<string> list = new List<string>();

if (sqlReader != null)
    {
        if (sqlReader.HasRows)
        {
            while (sqlReader.Read())
            {
                //return sqlReader[0].ToString();
                list.Add(sqlReader[0].ToString());
            }
            sqlConn.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
return list; // ta-da
```

Comment: @ebyrob yes :-) he will be aware of his columns and he can modify it according to his requirements :-)

Comment: This code is not generic enough, the code should work with any kind of columns matching an arbitrary contract....

Comment: @eloycm huh .. a generic approach could be to iterate over all columns (via their names) -> old argument "first column". (have done that in 2008 - performance is going down) subsequent, type casts could be used -> argument "arbitrary". ...... #performance.     "arbitrary contract" -> why using a contract when everything should work arbitrary?(rhetorical question) if you are aware about a link regarding template functions which are suitable to your comment, then feel free to post it. :-)

Answer (score 5):

You need to define DataContract, If you pass list of strings or array of strings your service consumers need to know which index is for which column etc.. that approach will be hard when you adding or deleting column to the service in future. What you can do is create DataContract which having all the properties you need to send and create the operation contract accordingly. Now service consumers can update the service reference in future in case of changing field they will get compiler error. that is easy to identify.

```
public List<MyDataContract>  GetData()
{
    List<MyDataContract> list = new List<MyDataContract>();
    //your code

    if (sqlReader != null)
    {
        if (sqlReader.HasRows)
        {
            while (sqlReader.Read())
            {
                list.Add(new MyDataContract() { 
                    Id = (int)sqlReader["Id"].ToString(), 
                    Name= sqlReader = sqlReader["Name"].ToString() });

            }
            sqlConn.Close();
        }
    }

    //finally return list of data

    return list;
}
```

Sample Data Contract

```
[DataContract]
public class MyDataContract
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

And Operation contract

```
     [OperationContract]
     List<MyDataContract> GetData();
```

---

> in my opinion we need more generic reusable code...

If you have only the .net Service consumers you can return **DaTaSet or DataTable** from the service method. You need to have **SqlDataAdapter** instead of sqlReader and Fill the DataTable Or Dataset and Return it. You can parace any number of columns no change in Service method definition. You can even send return type as string by using `DataSet.GetXml()`

**Converting DataTable To Json**

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table, Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: you are assuming that the object has an Id and an Name properties, In my opinion we need more generic reusable code...

Comment: @eloycm How About DataSet Or DaTaTable as Return Type, You don't even need to read line by line.

Comment: You can do it but I prefer sending objects... The ideal for me would be to forget about soap, data contracts and all that stuff, convert the whole thing to json and serve it via a nice restful service  ;)

Comment: I understand the concern about reading line by line,but I've tried it with good performance results. And I have the impression that GetXml will actually read trough the rows as well...

Comment: @eloycm try [Json.net](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json) you can convert DataTable to Json

Answer (score 1):

SqlReader is intended to work memory minimized and therefore will only query the result one by one. If you want to get all results you can use a while loop around your code to fetch rows as long as they are available. By calling return you will break the while loop and returning only first row. If you would call yield return an `IEnumerable<string>` would be returned by your method instead of `string`.

Comment: Thanks, haven't heard of the "yield" before. I'll try to Google it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably create an array or List and populate the List with your sqlReader.
List and Array can be serialized and transferred using WCF and are inter-operable too.

Inside the while loop

```
listObject.Add(sqlReader[0].ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I have updated my answer. I need to transfer everything that the SQL query gets back to the client, not only one column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually read all the datareader rows by loading them into a datatable, the datareader is a lazyload object and can't be sent across the network since it's never fully populated at the begning:

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();     
dt.Load(dr);
```

Then, since you are using wcf, you *possibly* need to load that datatable into an object matching your contract interface. Take a look the snipet below that converts an arbitrary datatable into a well behaved object matching properties by using reflection.

Snippet usage

```
List<myType> r = (List<myType>) dt.ToList<myType>();
```

Snippet

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Reflection;

namespace xxxx.Sql.Extensions
{
    public static class DataTableExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a list of objects  based on a generic datatable
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">List of objects</typeparam>
        /// <param name="table">Existing datatable</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IList<T> ToList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : new()
        {
            IList<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().ToList();
            IList<T> result = new List<T>();

            foreach (var row in table.Rows)
            {
                var item = CreateItemFromRow<T>((DataRow)row, properties);
                result.Add(item);
            }

            return result;
        }

        private static T CreateItemFromRow<T>(DataRow row, IList<PropertyInfo> properties) where T : new()
        {
            T item = new T();

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                if (row.Table.Columns.Contains(property.Name))
                {
                    var prop = row[property.Name] == System.DBNull.Value ? null : row[property.Name];
                    property.SetValue(item, prop, null);
                }
            }
            return item;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Creat a generic string list on the first field of a dataTable
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="table"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static List<string> ToStringList(this DataTable table)
        {
            List<string> result = new List<string>();

            foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
                result.Add(dr[0].ToString());

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ancient thread, but I'll add my two:

```
        string sqltext = @"select a.columnown, a.columntwo, a.columnthreee from blahblah as a";
        List<List<string>> toReturn = new List<List<string>>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = sqlTest;

            using (SqlDataReader sqlReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (sqlReader != null)
                {
                    if (sqlReader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (sqlReader.Read())
                        {
                            List<string> innerList = new List<string>();
                            for (int i = 0; i < sqlReader.FieldCount; i++)
                            {
                                innerList.Add(sqlReader[i].ToString());
                            }
                            toReturn.Add(innerList);
                        }
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

then you just simply return your `List<List<string>>`