# how does one pass each row in a query's resultset to a c# list

Tags: c#, list

how does one pass each row in a query's resultset to a C# List

so far what I have tried in doing is pass the resultset to a SQLDataReader then iterate its contents within a C# List.

the list sample reference i used was in this link:
[How to return SqlDataReader in C# WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571164/how-to-return-sqldatareader-in-c-sharp-wcf)

//Query

```
        string comm = "SELECT " +
                      "Name" +
                      "Local" +
                      "Employee_Number" +
                      "Employee_Name" +
                      "FROM t_temp_list";

        SqlCommand sel = new SqlCommand(comm,con);
```

//DataReader
    SqlDataReader rdr;

```
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            rdr= sel.ExecuteReader();
            pullShuffledData(rdr);
        }
        catch(SqlException ex)
        {
            Alert.Show("Error:"+ ex);
        }
```

//List within a method

```
    public void pullShuffledData(SqlDataReader rdr)
    {
        List<shuffleDataList> callList = new List<shuffleDataList>();
        //callList.Add

        if (rdr != null)
        {
            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    //return sqlReader[0].ToString();
                    callList.Add(rdr[0].ToString());
                }
                sqlConn.Close();
            }
            else
            {
              return null;
            }
        }
        return callList;
```

but I don't know how to output each resultset's row into a variable within the List's iteration. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: why doesn't this work - what error are you getting ? what is the structure of `shuffleDataList` ?

Comment: Vishnu,
Try using the 'yield' keyword as explained in the following post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252531/returning-a-sqldatareader

Comment: @bhs what I would like to achieve is for each resultset row to be pass on a variable within the list iteration or pass the row value to a List variable so that it can be accessed outside of pullShuffledData method. I am very new in C# and not really familiar yet with Lists in C#. Thanks

Comment: so create `callList` outside of the `pullShuffledData` method and then pass it in as a parameter. Get yourself a book on C# basics and look at variable scope, functions etc. The list contains a class probably called `shuffleDataList`. It's just a collection of objects. Create an instance of `shuffleDataList` within your data reader and add it to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `shuffleDataList` is a class defined as:

```
class shuffleDataList
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Local {get;set;}
    public string Employee_Number {get;set;}
    public string Employee_Name {get;set;}
}
```

Then, you can populate your list with `shuffleDataList` objects as follows:

```
public List<shuffleDataList> pullShuffledData(SqlDataReader rdr)
{
    List<shuffleDataList> callList = new List<shuffleDataList>();

    if (rdr != null)
    {
        if (rdr.HasRows)
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                callList.Add(new shuffleDataList()
                     {
                         Name = rdr.GetString(0), //Name column
                         Local = rdr.GetString(1), //Local column
                         Employee_Number = rdr.GetString(2), //Employee_Number column
                         Employee_Name = rdr.GetString(3), //Employee_Name column
                     });
            }
            sqlConn.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return callList; 
}
```